# Model persistence in MVC3 - Models being set to null & not being saved,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im persisting my data in MVC3 and have come across an annoying problem:

Lets say I have `MyModel a = new MyModel()` & `MyModel b = new MySubmodel()` defined in my constructor.

When I visit page 1:

```
 if (MyModel.MySubmodel== null)
  {
    //populate with defaults
  }else{
     //use existing model data
  }
```

On page 1, I can change the values using `Html.textboxFor` fields. I have my model updating with:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Page1(Mysubmodel model)
        {

            MyModel.Mysubmodel = model;
            return RedirectToAction("Page2", "Tool");
        }
```

using a watch ,I can see that my model is updating with the new values! (which is great!), however, If i try to return to my page to check if the results are saved they are set to null again

Code:

```
 public class MyController : Controller
{
  //set up initial models
       public MyModel mainmodel = new MyModel ();
       public MySubModel submodel = new MySubModel ();
 public ActionResult Page1()
        {
            tempList.Clear();
            service.XmlParseDefault(Request); //Acquire defaults
            //setup model 
            //could possibly throw this into .services if it becomes a "fat controller"
            if (mymodel.submobdel == null)
            {
                //Apply default values
            }
        return View(submodel);
}

 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Page1(submodel model)
        {

            mymodel.submodel = model;
            return RedirectToAction("Page2", "homecontroller");
        }


}
```

Comment: Do you store the model anywhere at all? In the Db, or at least in Session? Post completer code.

Comment: Currently its just stored in the constructors "a" instance of mymodel.

Comment: @RawryLions - I am assuming that you are initialising the model in the constructor but the model isn't actually stored in the constructor, it is defined in the controller?  Is this assumption correct? If it is created in the constructor then after the constructor completes the model will be lost.

Comment: You are not storing the value anywhere. The instance is dumped as soon as the page is rendered to you.

Comment: @RawryLions- Can you edit your question to show more of the controller please?  In particular, the constructor you are discussing and any models you may have defined in the controller, your Page1 GET and POST actions and Page2 GET action.

Comment: If you want to have such a behavior, you can use a static class in your constructor. This class will live as long as the IIS application is recycled

Comment: DUDE , YOU ARE ON THE WEB AND USING HTTP ....STATES ARE NOT PRESERVED ....your models are destroyed after the page is constructed and send to the browser

Comment: What if i used ViewData in my postback to store the `MyModel`? Would I be right in thinking that this would store the entire model(with submodels), then read it in in the constructor of the page. Also I assume that unlike sessions, ViewData is autodestroyed after one use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTTP : request/response protocol**

Once a request is fulfilled by the Server by rendering the appropriate response (can be html, xml or json) to the Client, everything is flushed out of the memory. (Exceptions to this are session states).

Therefore, in your case, when a request is received, the two model instances are created in the constructor and destroyed after the controller class goes out of scope i.e. it renders the view. So, when your form is submitted, the instances for the models are again created and that's why they always show null values.

> What if i used ViewData in my postback to store the MyModel? Would I be right in thinking that this would store the entire model(with submodels), then read it in in the constructor of the page. Also I assume that unlike sessions, ViewData is autodestroyed after one use?

Don't user ViewData, always use model and pass them to the views. Retrieve them when you post back. Assign the postback model to new instances of models and save the changes somewhere persistent. Like in a database or xml file.

Using a Static class can help you out, but it's not recommended. Because as i said, these classes live as long as the application recycles. Use a database or xml file. Even for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

After you perform the Redirect the model will be lost as the controller will be recreated on the GET request for Page2.

So your question is ultimately, how do you store the submodel model during the redirect from page1 to page2.

I guess it depends what the model contains?

If the information in the model does not contain sensitive information then I don't see anything wrong with storing the model values in hidden form fields to be recreated in the submodel by the default model binder in Page2 (keep in mind that a malicious user could change the values).

If the information is more sensitive (or some of it is) then the sensitive information could be passed using TempData (note that this is will be removed from TempData once it is read in Page2) or in the Session so that it will be stored during the entire user session.

Or if the information is more permanent then it could be written to the database and the model recreated when necessary using this information.